# ArcPy to View Unplaced Labels in ArcMap

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, labeling

Is there any way to access functions behind Labeling tool bar via ArcPy? Specifically I am interested in ArcPy command to turn off ***View Unplaced Labels***. I have found only some guide on workaround turning labels into annotations and checking output table to find any entries where STATUS=1. That seems to be ridiculous for something which is manually done by pressing one button via interface.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no, you cannot alter that property using arcpy, it's one of many properties that is simply not exposed through arcpy in ArcMap.

At best you can turn labels on/off with this code:

```py
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd,)[0]
lyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "mylayername", df)[0]
lyr.showLabels = False
```

You can tweak a label through accessing it's [LabelClass](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/labelclass-class.htm) object but you still cannot turn on/off unplaced labels

Comment: Thank you, I was hoping that in newer ArcMap versions at least some UI functions could be exposed in the similar way as it is in ArcPro via Python CIM access. Fair enough.